# The char type in Java behaves somewhat in a strange way?

Tags: java, char

Let's consider the following simple expressions in Java.

```
char c='A';
int i=c+1;

System.out.println("i = "+i);
```

This is perfectly valid in Java and returns **66**, the corresponding value of the  character (Unicode) of c+1.

---

```
String temp="";
temp+=c;
System.out.println("temp = "+temp);
```

This is too valid in Java and the String type variable **temp** automatically accepts c of type char and produces **temp=A** on the console.

---

All the following statements are also surprisingly valid in Java!

```
Integer intType=new Integer(c);
System.out.println("temp = "+intType);

Double  doubleType=new Double(c);
System.out.println("temp = "+doubleType);

Float floatType=new Float(c);
System.out.println("temp = "+floatType);

BigDecimal decimalType=new BigDecimal(c);
System.out.println("temp = "+decimalType);
```

Although c is a type of char, it can be supplied with no error in the respective constructors and all of the above statements are treated as valid statements. They produce the following outputs respectively.

```
temp = 65
temp = 65.0
temp = 65.0
temp = 65
```

---

In such a scenario, what is the internal behavior of the **char** type available in Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Char is a primitive numeric integral type and as such is subject to all the rules of these beasts including conversions and promotions. You'll want to read up on this, and the JLS is one of the best sources for this: [Conversions and Promotions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html). In particular, read the short bit on "5.1.2 Widening Primitive Conversion".

Answer (score 0):

char is sort of like a 16-bit int. You can concatenate integers other things onto Strings. It's a shortcut for Character.toString(c).

You can use the Character object if you wish to avoid such confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The primitives `char` and `byte` are interchangeable (which refers to the Unicode table values) - so yes, `char` variables can be treated as numerics, just as `byte` can.

Edit:
*Further to Henery's comment below, you are right of course, Java does use unicode to represent character content (original text updated to reflect this) - but as we know, the first 127 ASCII and Unicode chars more or less match, and so any manipulation performed within the character range 0..127 would be the same for both ASCII and Unicode, meaning that converting between the two are trivial.*

*The old-timers amongst us were probably taught and remember most of the ASCII table, rather than the Unicode table, and indeed I still keep a ASCII crib sheet in my desk for quick referal. Oh, and +1 for Henery's comment, for making me actually clarify what I wrote.*

Comment: As per I know, Java uses Unicode and not ASCII to represent corresponding characters. Please, clarify it.